# Segfault on Mongrel_Rails start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

When I run mongrel_rails start for my application, I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/http11.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-darwin10]
```

I am running Snow Leopard and Ruby, Rails, and PostgreSQL 8.4 via MacPorts.

UPDATE: Even if I attempt to do mongrel_rails -h above error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Had to sudo this command on my current machine.